Keep list of user-definitions
Is there some easy way to keep track of user defined definitions. Or perhaps even better definitions made while some definitionRecordingFlag==True.
This is prompted by this question How to obtain all definitions in which a symbol appears? (and related ones such as How to find all function which cannot be ToExpression?) where it was pointed out that scanning over all symbols for definitions can be dangerous because it is impossible to avoid all evaluation of symbols when performing such a scan.
If we can keep track of a list of only our user defined definitions we would have a much safer space to search over.

The easiest way to achieve this seems to be to define a setDelayed and set (mirroring the appropriate holding attributes from their partner function) that will first save the definition and then become their build in partner function. However, this kind of monitoring is often most useful for inspecting and understanding code you are loading possibly from other sources. So it would be better to overwrite these functions to avoid having to replace every instance of them. However, overwriting such basic functions might requires some very special care.
